# Why are some of libhandy library functions missing?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, meson-build

I am building a C application that includes gtk and libhandy libraries. I am using the meson build system through which I am compiling bundling the <handy.h> library.

```
libhandy_dep = dependency('libhandy-1', version: '>= 1.0.0', required: false)

    if not libhandy_dep.found()
      libhandy = subproject(
        'libhandy',
        default_options: [
          'examples=false',
          'glade_catalog=disabled',
          'introspection=disabled',
          'tests=false',
          'vapi=false',
        ]
      )
      libhandy_dep = libhandy.get_variable('libhandy_dep')
    endif
```

I have the libhandy repository cloned as a subproject to my project.
When I use several things from `<handy.h>` it works fine, for example the conversion macros and object declarations. But main functions like `hdy_init()` don't seem to work. The compiler doesn't understand those functions. In the file in which I am trying to call `hdy_init()` I have included the library as such:

```
  #define  HANDY_USE_UNSTABLE_API
  #include <handy.h>
```

I am not sure what additional information may be needed for this question so please let me know how I can improve the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was that I hadn't cloned the latest version of the libhandy library as a sub project and that's why some of the functionality from the library was missing.